# Failing to create my first dynamic GUI Calculator

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm, calculator

Does anybody know how to build a dynamic calculator that functions as follows:

GUI With Buttons and 4 Display Text Widgets (Number1, Operator, Number2, Result)

1. *First Number to be pushed is number1 (append number1 if multiple
   pushed)*
2. *Next the operator has to be pushed (change operator if multiple pushed)*
3. *Next number2 has to be pushed (append number2 if multiple pushed)*
4. *If "=" is pushed, print result*
5. *If "=" is not pushed but any other operator (+-,/,*) print result and save  next operator, - save result as number1 for next operation*

I am a beginner at coding and after several months of learning I decided to create a calculator in Python with tkinter. I have to say that I did not ask anyone for help until now.

It probably won't work but below you can find my try of creating my first program..:

```
from tkinter import *
import operator


root = Tk()

display1 = None
display2 = None

number1 = None
number2 = None
result = None
op_char = None
op_func = None
op_display = None

T_num1 = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T_num1.pack()
T_num2 = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T_num2.pack()
T_op = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
T_op.pack()
T_result = Text(root,height=2, width=30)
T_result.pack()

ops = {"+": operator.add,
   "-": operator.sub,
   "*": operator.mul,
   "/": operator.truediv}

def numberpush(input):

global result
global number1
global number2
global result
global op_char
global op_func
global op_display
global ops
global display1
global display2


if result != None:


    if number1 != None:

        if number2 == None:

            number2 = input
            display2 = input
            result = op_func(display1, number2)
            number1 = result
        else:
            number2.append(input)
            display2.append(input)
            T_num2.insert(END, display2)
            result = op_func(display1, display2)
            number1 = result

    else:
        number1 = result
        display2 = result
        T_num2.insert(END, display2)





elif operator_func == None:

    if number1 == None:

        number1 = input
        display1 = input
        T_num1.insert(END, display1)

    else:

        number1 = number1.append(input)
        display1.append(input)
        T_num1.insert(END, display1)


else:
    number2 = input
    display2 = input
    T_num2.insert(END, display2)

    result = op_func(number1, number2)

    number1 = result  # Set Number1 to Result

    operator_func = None  # Reset Operator to none
    op_display = None
    T_op.insert(END, op_display)


def buttonpush(input):

global result
global number1
global number2
global result
global op_char
global op_func
global op_display
global ops
global display1
global display2

if number1 == None:

    pass


elif result != None:

    # Check if Previous Calculation has been done, if so -> display the result of previous calc and save new operator

    display1 = result
    T_num1.insert(END, display1)

    number2 = None
    display2 = None
    T_num2.insert(END, display2)

    op_char = input
    op_func = ops[op_char]
    op_display = input
    T_op.insert(END, op_display)

    result = None  # Reset the Result

else:
    op_char = input
    op_func = ops[op_char]
    op_display = input
    T_op.insert(END, op_display)




def result():

global result
global number1
global number2
global result
global op_char
global op_func
global op_display
global ops
global display1
global display2

if number1 !=None and number2 != None and op_func == None:

    if result == None:

        T_result.insert(END, number1)

    else:

        T_result.insert(END, result)


elif number1 != None and op_func != None:

    T_result.insert(END, "Error")


elif number1 != None:

    T_result.insert(END, number1)

else:

     T_result.insert(END, "Waiting")







button_0 = Button(root, text="0", command=numberpush(0))
button_0.pack()

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", command=numberpush(1))
button_1.pack()

button_2 = Button(root, text="2", command=numberpush(2))
button_2.pack()

button_3 = Button(root, text="3", command=numberpush(3))
button_3.pack()

button_4 = Button(root, text="4", command=numberpush(4))
button_4.pack()

button_5 = Button(root, text="5", command=numberpush(5))
button_5.pack()

button_6 = Button(root, text="6", command=numberpush(6))
button_6.pack()

button_7 = Button(root, text="7", command=numberpush(7))
button_7.pack()

button_8 = Button(root, text="8", command=numberpush(8))
button_8.pack()

button_9 = Button(root, text="9", command=numberpush(9))
button_9.pack()

button_add = Button(root, text="+", command=buttonpush("+"))
button_add.pack()

button_subtract = Button(root, text="-", command=buttonpush("-"))
button_subtract.pack()

button_multiply = Button(root, text="*", command=buttonpush("*"))
button_multiply.pack()

button_divide = Button(root, text="/", command=buttonpush("/"))
button_divide.pack()

button_result = Button(root, text="=", command=result())
button_result.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you run the code? What happend? Also, please note there is a separate domain for code review:https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I didn't know that. I get the following message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  Calculator.py", line 201, in <module>
    button_1 = Button(root, text="1", command=numberpush(1))
 Calculator.py", line 61, in numberpush
    result = op_func(display1, number2)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable